# Skilled Based Routing in Omni Channel

Tags: omnichannel

I am trying to make some skilled based routing in Omni Channel for Call Centre Agents, is this possible in Omni Channel. If Yes how can i achieve to make Skill Based Routing from Queues to Agents.

Thanks

Comment: I am looking for the same. Please update if you have got anything on this.

Comment: This is not supported as of yet. Its a Salesforce idea https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000Tpz5QAC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a custom picklist field on Case object (This is the standard
   object in SF). Add all your skills into field.
2. Add the respective skills in the Omni Channel Skills (Attached image for reference) Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jQLk.png
3. Go to skills based routing rules (https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jQLk.png) and then create a new skills based mapping set on the case object
4. Create service resources based on your requirement and give each service resource a specific skill.
5. The incoming cases based on the skills should be routed to a particular agent without any hassle.

Answer (score 1):

The common way to work with skilled routing at the moment, is to create different Queues per Skill. You can assign users or groups to that Queues, and use them with Omni-Channel.